# How to connect Torodb and Django?

Tags: django, mongodb, postgresql

Does anyone know how to connect Torodb and Django? I have been reading about it and it seems like a good idea, but it is not very popular and because that there are not many of the "how to..." related with Torodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't support NoSQL out of the box, but there's the [Django Non-Rel](http://django-nonrel.org/) project, which *does* support MongoDb 
The list of [supported databases is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#using-a-3rd-party-database-backend).

Since ToroDB is built on MongoDb, you may get away with using Django Non Rel - it depends whether the django backend picks up ToroDb properly, but my [reading of this for example, is that this will work.](http://pythonhackers.com/p/torodb/torodb), as it seems to be db-api compliant.

If that doesn't work, you could connect to the database manually, and run raw Otherwise you'll need to write your own database backend - the SQLite one is a [readable place to start](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py) in looking at them.